# Regex for bigquery to return all paths after /api

Tags: regex, github, google-bigquery

I am using dataset of github to extract all paths after /api/* and for that I used this below-mentioned query. However, the results are not what I expected it to be. If the regex is wrong can someone please correct it?

Expected results:

- /api/v1/user
- /api/anything/anything

What actually returns:

- Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework/Resources
- doc/source/README.rst

````
  *
FROM 
   `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files`
WHERE
(REGEXP_CONTAINS(path,r'(s|^.*/api/([^/]*)(?:/.*)?$|$1|)'))
LIMIT
100```
````

Comment: Try `REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, r'^/api/[^/]*(?:/.*)?$')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the answer but now the query results as "This query returned no results."

Comment: Well, the regex is [working](https://regex101.com/r/YpjxfF/2)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Perl `s`ubstitution command in the regex *pattern*. Look:

```
s|^.*/api/([^/]*)(?:/.*)?$|$1 |
||                        |RHS
||___pattern______________|
|___ action
```

where `RHS` (right-hand side) is the *replacement*.

You only need to use a *pattern* in BigQuery. To match your desired strings, you may use

```
^/api/[^/]*(?:/.*)?$
```

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YpjxfF/2).

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files`
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(path,r'^/api/[^/]*(?:/.*)?$')
    LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

> If the regex is wrong can someone please correct it?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, r'/api/.*')
LIMIT 100
```

Meantime, note: title of your question is not consistent with question body - `REGEXP_CONTAINS` in *WHERE* clause just allows you to return all rows with searched pattern in path - but does not extract the pattern.

To extract pattern - you need to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r'/api/.*')` in SELECT statement.